# Error in classes - missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-class

I am actually learning python3 and not able to figure it why it is so

```
class Load():
    def __init__(self):
        print("Starting Now")
        self.player = []
    def player_Stats(self,filename):
        with open(filename) as my_names:
            names = my_names.readlines()
            for one in names:
                one.replace("\n","")
                self.player.append(one.split[":"][0])
                print(player)


print(Load.player_Stats("players.txt"))
```

It is giving me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 56, in <module>
    print(Load.player_Stats("players.txt"))
TypeError: player_Stats() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'
```

and I am not getting it why.

Comment: Are you intending that method to be a static/class method? You have it as in instance method, but you're calling it on the class itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Missing one required positional argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50594457/7414759)

Answer (score 2):

You have to define an object or make the function static.
**Option 1: Define Object:**

```
class Load():
    def __init__(self):
        print("Starting Now")
        self.player = []
    def player_Stats(self,filename):
        with open(filename) as my_names:
            names = my_names.readlines()
            for one in names:
                one.replace("\n","")
                self.player.append(one.split[":"][0])
                print(player)

load = Load()
print(load.player_Stats("players.txt"))
```

**Option 2: Static method:**

```
class Load():
    def __init__(self):
        print("Starting Now")
        self.player = []
    @staticmethod
    def player_Stats(filename):
        with open(filename) as my_names:
            names = my_names.readlines()
            for one in names:
                one.replace("\n","")
                self.player.append(one.split[":"][0])
                print(player)


print(Load.player_Stats("players.txt"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```py
lass Load():
    def __init__(self):
        print("Starting Now")
        self.player = []
    def player_Stats(self,filename):
        with open(filename) as my_names:
            names = my_names.readlines()
            for one in names:
                one.replace("\n","")
                self.player.append(one.split[":"][0])
                print(player)

load = Load()

print(load.player_Stats("players.txt"))
```

The problem was that when you have a class, you must create an instance of it. Then you can call it's methods.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new instance of `Load` in order to use the `player_Stats` method:

```py
load = Load()
print(load.player_Stats("players.txt"))
```

Also, there are some other errors in your code:

```py
self.player.append(one.split[":"][0])
# should be
self.player.append(one.split(":")[0])

print(player)
# should be
print(self.player)
```