# How exactly do parentheses work when it comes to classes, methods, and instances in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Classes, methods, and instances have me **thoroughly** confused. Why is it that this works:

```
class Computer:
    
    def config(self):
        print('i5, 16gb, 1TB')

com1 = Computer()
com1.config()
```

But this does not?:

```
class Computer:
    
    def config(self):
        print('i5, 16gb, 1TB')

com1 = Computer()
Computer.config()
```

But, if you modify the code directly above to include the instance as an argument when calling the method, like so:

```
Computer.config(com1)
```

it works? I see the difference between the two, but I don't understand it.

Comment: Actually `instance.method()` does a call to `class.method(instance)` in the background. (That behaviour might be modified by decorators.)

Comment: `com1` is an instance of the class `Computer`. They are not interchangeable.

Comment: This question already has answers here:[TypeError: Missing one required positional argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50594457/7414759)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example `Computer.config` is an instance method, means it is bound to an object, or in other words **requires** an object. Therefore in your second example you would write:

```
com1.config()
```

You can also write it in the following style:

```
Computer.config(com1)
```

which is the same and just syntactic sugar. In same special cases you might prefer the latter one, e.g. when [duck typing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/duck-typing-in-python/) is required, but the first one is definitely the preferred way.

In addition, there are [staticmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) or [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) functions, which don't require any objects. An example would be this:

```
class Computer
    @staticmethod
    def config():
        print("Foo")

Computer.config()  # no object required at all, because its a staticmethod
```

Please notice the missing `self` reference. Technically `Computer.config` as a staticmethod is just a simple function, but it helps to group functionalities so to make them a class member.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. If `Computer.config` is bound to an object, making it an instance method, then what is `com1.config()` if not an instance method? And what makes one an instance method? I thought that an instance of a class was just the creation of the object? Sorry, I'm just finding it hard to understand.

Comment: No classifier at all around a method makes it **always** an instance method which requires an object. ONLY `staticmethod` and `classmethod` make them non-bound methods which are often used as convinience functions for certain tasks

Comment: To sum it up, `com1.config()` OR `Computer.config(com1)` is exactly the same, but first is preferred and means instance method. Only my last method shows you how to make a non-instance method

Answer (score 0):

This is because `config()` is an instance method, and not a static method. An instance method, simply said, is shared across all objects of a class, and cannot be accessed by just using the class name. If you want to call `config()` by just using class name, you have to tell compiler that it is static. To do this use `@staticmethod` tag, and remove the `self` argument:

```
 class Computer:
    @staticmethod
    def config():
        print('i5, 16gb, 1TB')

com1 = Computer()
com1.config()
```

And as you said:

> if you modify the code directly above to include the instance as an
> argument when calling the method, like so:

This is because, every instance function takes `self` as it's first argument. Basically `self` is somewhat similar to `this` in C++ or Java, and it tells which object to work upon, i.e., `self` acts as a pointer to the current object. When you passed the `com1` object to the argument, it took self for `com1`.

That means that when you invoke `com1.config()` what you are actually doing is calling `config` with `com1` as its argument. So `com1.config(()` is the same as `Computer.config(com1)`.

Answer (score -1):

### Why doesn't the second approach work?

Because `Computer` is an instance of something called a meta-class. It is somewhat the class definition and not actually an instance of `Computer`. `com1` is an instance created by `Computer`. You can use `com1` to invoke its non-static functions but you can't use the meta-class `Computer` to invoke non-static functions, which need an object to be ran on.

### Why does the third approach work?

Have you noticed the `self` in the definition of the `config` function? That means that when you invoke `com1.config()` what you are actually doing is calling `config` with `com1` as its argument. So `com1.config()` is the same as `Computer.config(com1)`.

Comment: `Computer` is a **class**, not a metaclass. A metaclass is something else.

Comment: @khelwood `Computer`, when used as an object, is an instance of a meta-class. It is a class but an instance of meta-class. The second code uses `Computer` like an instance so it behaves like an instance of a meta-class.

Comment: If you think it's important to explain how classes are instances of metaclasses, OK, but it's pretty irrelevant to the question. But your answer still says "the meta-class Computer" instead of "the *class* Computer".