# Missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, positional-argument

I have created a Python class:

```py
class calculator:
    
    def addition(self,x,y):
        added = x + y
        print(added)
        
    def subtraction(self,x,y):
        sub = x - y
        print(sub)

    def multiplication(self,x,y):
        mult = x * y
        print(mult)

    def division(self,x,y):
        div = x / y
        print(div)
```

Now when I am calling the function like this:

```
calculator.addition(2,3)
```

I am getting an error:

> addition() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

What is the problem? What could be the solution so that I can call it like `addition(2,3)`?

Comment: The problem is that you have to either create instance of class or declare methods as static.

Comment: Read up on [TypeError: Missing one required positional argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50594457/7414759) and [Tutorial - 9.3. A First Look at Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python' classes have three types of methods:

1. Instance method

The instance method must pass the instance object as the first parameter to the method, which is `self`, like:

```py
class calculator:
    
    def addition(self, x, y):
        added = x + y
        print(added)

c = calculator()        
c.addition(2, 3)
```

2. Class method

The class method use `classmethod` decorator and must pass the class object as the first parameter to the method, which is `cls`, like:

```py
class calculator:
    
    @classmethod
    def addition(cls, x, y):
        added = x + y
        print(added)
    
calculator.addition(2, 3)
```

3. Static method

The static method doesn’t matter, just add an `staticmethod` decorator, like:

```py
class calculator:
    
    @staticmethod
    def addition(x, y):
        added = x + y
        print(added)
    
calculator.addition(2, 3)
```

So, the last two ways can be your answer if you just want to call with a class object like `calculator.addition(2, 3)`.

Comment: Than you so much for this explanation. Your solution cleared my doubt for classmethod and static methods.

Comment: @FarazKhan No problem :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass in the `self` variable by actually declaring an instance of this class, like this:

`myCalculator = calculator()`

`myCalculator.addition(2,3)`

Output should be: `5`

Answer (score 1):

Please create a instance of the class first:

```
calculator_instance = calculator()
```

Then, you can call the function as `calculator_instance.addition(2,3)`

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use the name "Calculator" for your class
2. When you call the function Caculator.addition you need 3 args (self, x, y) but you gived 2
3. You should write your function «addition(self,x,y):» like this «addition(self, x: int, y: int):»

If you just want the function addition write it not as a class methode but as a function.
If you need write «calculator.addition(2,3)» first do `calculator = Calculator()`

Answer (score -1):

You just neet to delete self. Self will be used when you have  __init __ function

```
class calculator:
    
    def addition(x,y):
        added = x + y
        print(added)
        
    def subtraction(x,y):
        sub = x - y
        print(sub)

    def multiplication(x,y):
        mult = x * y
        print(mult)

    def division(x,y):
        div = x / y
        print(div)

calculator.addition(2,3)
```