# "missing 1 required positional argument" when calling class method

Tags: python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

class Main():
    def Login(self,username,password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get("http://instagram.com")
        time.sleep(5)
        login_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]/div/label/input')
        password_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[2]/div/label/input')
        login_input.send_keys(self.username)
        password_input.send_keys(self.password)
        

main = Main.Login("test","test")
```

The problem is that I am getting this error: `TypeError: Login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'password'`.
Anyone have solution?

Comment: You have to instantiate `Main` before calling `Login`.  Try: `main = Main().Login('test', 'test')`

Comment: You have to create an instance of your class before it's even meaningful to invoke methods.  `Main().Login("test","test")` for example, although you probably want to split the `Main()` off into a separate assignment statement, so that you have a reference to the instance later.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63085582/missing-1-required-positional-argument-y)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Missing one required positional argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50594441/2745495)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
main = Main.Login("test","test")
```

Should be:

```
main = Main().Login("test","test")
```

or:

```
main = Main()
main.Login("test","test")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method isn't a class method, so you can't access it with `Main.Login`. Add a `@classmethod` decorator to your function or create first an instance of Main and call your method on that instance.

Plus, your function doesn't return anything, so assigning it to a variable will just give you `None`.